# Print file up to Nth match

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to split a file up. `sed` can be used to do this, for example

```
sed -e '0,/expr/d' filename
```

would give the bottom half of the file after "expr" But what if there is more than one occurrence and I want to split after the nth occurrence? I figured out if I want it after the second occurrence then

```
sed -e '0,/expr/! {/expr/,$d}' filename
```

gives the top half of the file up to the second match of "expr". The exclamation point (!) tells it to ignore the first range and only apply the commands in the braces to the other parts of the file.

But what about more general cases? For example, from the second last occurrence.

I've been using `sed` here, but I think `awk` would have elegant solutions too.

Answer (score 2):

Simple awk solutions:

1. Up to and including the `$n`th match of `/regex/`:

   `awk -vn=$n '{print}/regex/&&!--n{exit}'`
2. Up to but not including the `$n`th match:

   `awk -vn=$n '/regex/&&!--n{exit}{print}'`

   In both the above programscases, setting n to 0 will print the whole file. Also, both uses of `{print}` can be changed to `1;` because the default action is `{print}`. (Or just `1` in the second program.)

   For completeness:
3. Everything after the `$n`th match:

   `awk -vn=$n 'n<=0;/regex/{--n}'`

Note: As pointed out in a comment by @mklement0, there is a bug in command-line option parsing in versions of BSD Awk (aka "one-true-awk", the version written and as far as I know still maintained by Brian Kernighan) prior to May 23, 2010; this apparently includes the version distributed with Mac OS X (as of v10.9). As a result, if you use one of these awk versions, you need to write `-v n=$n` instead of `-vn=$n`.

Comment: Great; if you reformat `-vn=$n` to `-v n=$n`, it'll work on OS X too.

Comment: @mklement0: which version of awk do you have on which version of OS X? the `-vn=$n` syntax works with every awk I've tried, including BSD awk which is what I thought OS X uses.

Comment: It's `awk version 20070501` (OS X 10.9) - strange, but that's what `awk --version` reports.

Comment: @mklement0: That's a surprisingly old version for a shiny new OS. The bug in parsing the -v option was apparently fixed in the version of May 23, 2010; see changelist here: http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/one-true-awk/FIXES

Comment: Yes, unfortunately many OSS components that come with OS X are quite old (another example: the bash version is `bash 3.2.51`) - at least in part, I think, the reason is political (licensing issues). Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

Some more variations of `awk` in addition to *@rici*'s solutions

1. Up to and including the `$n`th match:

   `awk -v n=$n 'p<n; /regex/{p++}' file`
2. Up to but not including the `$n`th match:

   `awk -v n=$n '/regex/{p++} p<n' file`
3. From and including `$n`th match

   `awk -v n=$n '/regex/{p++} p>=n' file`
4. From and not including `$n`th match

   `awk -v n=$n 'p>=n; /regex/{p++}' file`

---

> But what about more general cases? For example, from the second last
>   occurrence.

In that case simple approach would be to read file reverse with `tac`, do above options and print it again in reverse.

1. From and including `$n`th last match

   `tac file | awk -v n=$n 'p<n; /regex/{p++}' | tac`
2. From and not including `$n`the last match

   `tac file | awk -v n=$n '/regex/{p++} p<n' | tac`
3. Up to and including `$n`th last match

   `tac file | awk -v n=$n '/regex/{p++} p>=n' | tac`
4. Up to and not including `$n`th last match

   `tac file | awk -v n=$n 'p>=n; /regex/{p++}' | tac`

---

**Note for OS X users** as pointed out by *@mklement0* in comments

- Poor [stock] OS X users (as of OS X 10.9) are out of luck: no `tac` there.
- on OS X you can use `tail -r` (note that `tail` on Linux appears not to support `-r`).

Comment: Poor [stock] OS X users (as of OS X 10.9) are out of luck: no `tac` there.

Comment: @mklement0 I am not familiar with OS X and have used only Linux or Windows. Then how do you reverse the file content?

Comment: Thanks for inspiring me to look it up: on OS X you can use `tail -r` (note that `tail` on Linux appears not to support `-r`).

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for your comments. I have added them to ans for any OS X users.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr 'x;/^X{2}/{x;p;b};x;/REGEXP/{x;s/^/X/;x}' file
```

This will print out anything after the 2nd match of `REGEXP`.

N.B.The `REGEXP` may occur one or more times per line but will only be counted once.